# How to determine the size of a string in C, or at least ensuring that it doesn't exceed a maximum number of bytes?

Tags: c

Is it possible to determine the size in bytes of a string in C?

I'm trying to ensure that JSON strings built in C do not exceed a 1 MB size limit before passing them to the requesting application. I don't know the strings at compile time.

I've read that it is just `strlen * sizeof( char )`; but I don't understand that, because I read elsewhere that UTF-8 can have characters of size up to four bytes and `sizeof( char )` is always one.

I am likely misunderstanding something basic.

If a character array is allocated as `char JSON[1048576]`, does this allocate that many characters or bytes? If it is bytes, then as long as something like `snprintf` is used when writing to JSON array, would this guarantee that it can never exceed 1 MB in size, even if there were character in that array that exceed one byte?

Thank you.

Comment: A single `char` guarantees its size to be 1 byte.

Comment: @Rohan Bari Thank you. I came across a site that claims to calculate the byte size of any string in C and shows the example of  `i ♥ u` and says it's 7 bytes. If the heart is 3 bytes, how does `char` guarantee to be one byte, or does it take up 3 characters?

Comment: Yes, it does take up to 3 characters. [See demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/fnE956)

Comment: @RohanBari Thank you. I didn't realize it was that simple. I looked in the `<string.h>` header and since using minGW-W64, it has just one line that uses Windows' `strlen` function and they state that, "strlen interprets the string as a single-byte character string, so its return value is always equal to the number of bytes, even if the string contains multibyte characters." That's what I wasn't understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are after a size limit `1MB` and not a string length limit per se, you can just use `strlen(json_str)`. Provided that your json string is null terminated, `'\0'`.

If you allocate `char JSON[1048576]` that will give you an array with that many bytes. And `snprintf(JSON, 1048576, "<json string>", ...)` will guarantee that you never overfill your array.

It does not guarantee however that your string is a valid utf-8 string since the last character may be a multi byte character that is split in the middle.

A C `char` is not the same as a utf-8 character. In C `char` is by definition 1 Byte but in utf-8 the visual character that you want, like the heart in your comment, may be represented by several bytes of data.
One byte gives you 256 different values and since there are way more than 256 Unicode "characters" more than one byte is needed to encode many of them. The designers of utf-8 was clever though so the first 127 characters can be encoded using just one byte and if only those characters are used it will both valid utf-8 and ascii.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That part about breaking on a part of a multi-byte character is a bugger. Do you happen to know how that should be handled? If the `strlen` of the JSON exceeds 1MB, I've been escaping all the double quotes and passing it in pieces as a regular string and concatenating them in the requesting app. before attempting to parse as JSON. Even if the break was on a single byte character, it wouldn't be valid JSON in my case since it's only part of a full JSON string. I guess in the multi-byte scenario, after concatenating, it would still parse successfully?

Comment: Funny, too, in a way because I had the whole thing backwards, thinking that `strlen` was the length in characters regardless of byte size. Instead, `strlen` returns bytes and one doesn't know how many characters are in those bytes.

Comment: If the JSON can contain UTF-8, then you shouldn't use `strlen` anyway. You would have to use multibyte strings, widechar functions, conversions, etc. I would say that handling UTF-8 is probably an advanced topic.